# Path is wrong (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this chunk of code:

```
private void button4_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Resources/navigation.wav");
            player.Play();
        }
```

And I get FileNotFoundException, but navigation.wav is in Project/Resources. Plese help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is determined relatively from the executable, so in this case probably `Bin\Debug`.

Try to add the resource in your application as `Content` (it copies the file to `Bin\Debug`). That should work.

[image: build action]

Comment: Are you sure that the path is relative to the directory of the executable, and not to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? (They are usually the same, but not always.)

Comment: @Faruk: Did you check the `Build Action`? See my updated answer.

Comment: System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Bin\Debug\Resources\navigation.wav");

Comment: @PatrickHofman System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Resources\navigation.wav"); and still nothing... Im to stupid for this...

Comment: Does it say: Copy always and did you recompile?

Comment: O man i didnt see this "Copy always"... Sorry, I'm new in this area... It works now... Thanks A LOT!!!

Answer (score 2):

This looks for the file from your `Bin\Debug` Folder

You have couple of options:

- Right click the file and pick Properties. Select for BuildAction = Content.
  You will find the file under Bin\Debug\Resource\Sound.wav
- Right click the file and pick Properties. Select for BuildAction = Embedded Resource.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "NamespaceName.FolderName.Sound.wav";   
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    var wave = new WaveFileReader(stream);
    Console.WriteLine(wave.TotalTime);
}
```

Comment: There, in resources is this .wav file. How to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

That path is relative to the directory in which the application is currently running. If you hit F5 in Visual Studio this is most probably bin/Debug, so the file should be there.

Consider embedding this resource, or setting Copy to output directory property to "copy always".

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you need a backslash: `@"Resources\navigation.wav"`

If this doesn't help, then most likely you are running your application from a different directory than you think. Are you running in debug mode from VS? Is your file in `Project\bin\Debug\Resources` then?